# Origin of using "left" as something we still have

Tags: etymology, semantics

People express a quantity of something they still have (but is finding away) by using the word "left".

> *Time left: 2 hours*

Where does this usage originates from. If one depicts a timeline, it would be more useful to say "time right":

```
      |-- time right? --|
------|-----------------|--------->
     now              event
```

In short: how did direction get additional semantics in English?

Comment: If you check in a dictionary, you will find that there are two different words, 'left' and 'left'. Homonyms. They have different etymologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be me, but to me this derives not from left/right but simply from the verb to leave...

In french you'd say things like: "Il me reste X" or "Il reste X". (I'm left with X. X is left.)

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up

- [left](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/left?showCookiePolicy=true) (= *not right* side) and
- left (= past participle of *to leave*)

They sound the same, but have totally different origins, they are a classic example of a [homonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym).

Homonyms are defined as

> Words that share the same spelling and pronunciation but have different meanings. <sup>[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym)</sup>

Homonyms (or homophones = words that sound the same) are often used in jokes, where the "misunderstanding" is the base of the joke:

> *Why did the cat come down from the tree? Because it saw the tree bark.*

Answer (score 0):

Are you confusing the past tense/participle of *leave* with *left*?

#### Left1

[Middle English, from Old English lyft-, weak, useless (in lyftādl, paralysis). N., sense 2, from the fact that liberals often sit on the left side of the legislative chamber in various assemblies .]

#### Left2

v.
Past tense and past participle of leave1.

*[American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/left)*

#### [Leave 1](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/leave)

[Middle English leaven, from Old English lǣfan; see leip- in Indo-European roots.]